# Batch Script Delete files before date on Linux

Tags: linux, batch-file

I am trying to find a way to code a batch script to delete `x-xxx.jpg` that were created before a certain date.

How would this be done? 
So basically say I have `20k.jpg` and I want to create a batch script on Linux to run which will delete all images created let's say before 12th December 2011.

Comment: Files *created* before a certain date? Or *modified* before a certain date? Because in general Linux filesystems do not store the creation date of a file - unlike Windows. Well, `ext4` does store the creation date IIRC but the userspace has no standardized access to that timestamp...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of depending on a date, why cant we delete file those are 'N' days old?

For example here is the 'find' command to 'print' *.jpg files those were created before 2 days.

```
find /folder_path/ -iname '*.jpg' -type f -ctime  +1 -print
```

Note: replace the '-print' option with '-delete' if you want to delete files returned from the search result.

Here is an [excellent tutorial](http://find.unixpin.com/) for 'find' command

Comment: This is awesome. Better than using a file straight from putty thanks!

Comment: +1 for correctly addressing the [actual problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 1):

The following script uses the `-ot` test ("older to"):

```bsh
#/bin/bash
touch -d "$1" /tmp/D
shift
for file in "$@" ; do
    [[ $file -ot /tmp/D ]] && rm "$file"
done
rm /tmp/D
```

Save it as `delete-older.sh`, make it executable `chmod u+x delete-older.sh`, run it as

```
path/to/script/delete-older.sh 2011/12/12 *.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

`find . -name "*.jpg" -mtime +1 -ok rm {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

To delete jpg file older than, for example, 20 days:

```
find . -mtime +1 -name '*.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

on centos 4.4, you have to use single quote for `{}`,e.g.

```
# delete the "log/*.log" files that are 7 days ago. 
find log/*.log -mtime +7 -exec rm '{}' \;
```